# preserving visibility when doing an alias_method_chain on attr_accessor in Ruby 1.9

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9

I'm trying to port a library from ruby 1.8.  I didn't write the library.  I can change the API if absolutely necessary, but it does have a fair number of users I would prefer not to inconvenience.

Here's the problem simplified:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'activesupport'

class Foo
  private
  def self.attr_accessor_with_magic(*attrs)
    attr_accessor_without_magic(*attrs)
  end

  public
  class << self
    alias_method_chain :attr_accessor, :magic
  end

  attr_accessor :bar
end

foo=Foo.new
foo.bar=17
puts foo.bar
```

On Ruby 1.8.7p174, this prints `17`

On Ruby 1.9.1p243, I get ``` private method ``bar=' called for #<Foo:0x000000010a40f8> (NoMethodError) ```

Obviously, the Ruby 1.9 behaviour is correct.  To better illustrate the Ruby 1.8 bug replace the `public` with `private` in the above code.  Ruby 1.8 still prints `17`!

Therefore I can retain "bug compatibility" with the current version of the library by writing

```
  private
  def self.attr_accessor_with_magic(*attrs)
    public
    attr_accessor_without_magic(*attrs)
    private
  end
```

Does anybody have any idea how I can do the right thing and create the appropriate visibility for the attr?   On Ruby 1.8 it's going to be `public` no matter what I do, but is it possible to do the right thing for 1.9?

Answer (score 0):

If `attr_accessor` is not doing the right thing for you, you don't need to use it.  As far as I know, writing `attr_accessor :bar` is just a quick way to define two public methods, "bar" and "bar=" that get and set the member variable @bar.  So you can do that by hand instead, and add your own customizations and privacy levels to it:

```
class Foo
  public
  def bar
    reading_bar_magic()
    return @bar
  end

  private
  def bar=(value)
    setting_bar_magic()
    @bar=value
  end
end
```

Comment: Am I mis-understanding?  Does your library provide "attr_accessor_with_magic" for the user to use, or does it provide a class named Foo with an accessor called "bar"?

Comment: the library provides a method called `attr_accessor`.  It works the same as Module's `attr_accessor` except that it allows a couple of extra options to be passed.

Comment: or at least, it should work the same.  But it doesn't -- it cannot preserve the visibility.  Thus the question.